# How are the Westworld hosts powered?

Tags: westworld-2016

I can't remember any time the hosts power supply or charging time etc. was mentioned on the show.

How are the hosts powered?
 I'm thinking particularly in relation to ...

> Maeve's aborted escape attempt. What resources (such as power) would she have needed in the outside world to survive?

Did I miss something in the show? 
Are there other sources that answers this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## We don't know yet.

According to Jonathan Nolan via *Entertainment Weekly* (src: [**Polygon.com**](http://www.polygon.com/2016/11/15/13626044/westworld-creators-will-focus-on-the-hosts-builds-their-weaknesses-in-second-season))

> “Their construction and their power source is something we’re really going to get into during season two, “ Nolan said. “So we’d like to keep that mysterious.”
>
> Nolan added that they wanted to spend more time looking at how the hosts are made, because they’re far more biological than they are mechanical at this point, and examine what their main weakness is. Although they share many qualities with the people who created them, their brains are still quite different from human beings, making the process of killing them more difficult.
>
> “On one hand, their cognition is controllable and malleable, but on a structural level they can’t be killed in the same way you and I can,” Nolan said. “There are advantages and disadvantages to being a host. Season two we’ll be exploring more the nuts and bolts of what they are — as the hosts themselves are trying to understand.”

Nolan also added in “West Word” on Sky that the power source would be covered in Season 3.

Comment: At the risk of spoiling, S2 is over now, and they did not mention power source at all!

Comment: I don't recall anything about their power source in season 3 either.

Answer (score -4):

The thing that makes the most sense is some kind of nuclear power source. Or maybe their skin is made to be a type of solar panel, and they charge through absorbing the suns rays. They definitely get enough sun out in the desert climate of the park.

Comment: Why not something more like extracting energy from nutrients like biological processes? The producers have said they are more biological than mechanical at this point, so it naturally follows their energy source is as well.

Comment: I can see that being a very acceptable answer as well. The hosts obtaining energy by eating food would also Help them appear human. But, I don't remember seeing a host ever consume anything besides liquids. If they do a second season (which I don't think is necessary, the ending was perfect) they'll probably answer the power source question.

Comment: Love. Their source of energy is love.